# Exporting all conflicts in GIT in a text file

Tags: git

I need to show to the people that have to review the PR the conflicts I fixed.
Is there a way with git to export in a text file all the conflicts?

What I need is a text file with a "cat" of all the files containing a conflict after the merge

Comment: Have you considered using a patch file?

Comment: is it true that the patch file will show the changes but not the result of the merge with conflicts? What I mean is that I would see the original file (before the merge) and the final version: I would not see the conflicts I fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U` which lists files with unmerged conflicts and `cat`:

You should end up with something like:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs cat
```

And to have everything in a file, just redirect output:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs cat > conflicts.diff
```

Or just zip the files

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs zip -r9 conflicts.zip
```

Comment: to get only the names: "git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U > conflicts.txt"

Answer (score 2):

you can use this one as well:

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs  awk '/<<<<< HEAD/,/>>>>>>/'`

This cuts the conflicts (provided the conflicting areas start with `<<<<< HEAD` and end in `>>>>>>`) from the file so you can dump them to a new file - handy if original files are huge and you only need the conflicts to display.

Comment: Just what I needed - edited your post - hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "export ... all the conflicts"?

- Do you mean a list of conflicting files?

  Then use `git status --short` (terse) or just `git status` and pipe its output to a file (`git status >/tmp/conflicts.txt`).
- Do you mean the patch set with the work you've done to fix the conflicts?

  Then record one or more commits which fix the conflicts (possibly on a temporary branch) and then use `git format-patch <base_commit>..<current_tip>`.
- Do you mean the files as is with embedded conflict markers?

  Then identify such files from `git status` and just copy them from your work tree.

Comment: Right I need to get the resukt of the third method. I was wondering whether there is a faster way to do it

Comment: @James, I'm afraid there isn't because, honestly, your demand appears to be quite unusual. But fear not -- Git is highly scriptable. You can write a rather trivial program that would call `git status --porcelain` (which output is guaranteed to be stable between Git versions), parse it to detect conflicting paths and, say, output them to its standard output stream so that you could do something like `./print-conflicting-paths | xargs zip -r9 /tmp/conflicts.zip`

Comment: @James, please consult the [`git-status`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) manual page.  Actually, its `-z` command-line option might be even more suitable for machine processing (but *not* with POSIX shells which are notoriously bad when it comes to `NUL`s).  The machine-readable format is explained in detail.